# Height of a floating container

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding a simple case where you have 2 floating elements inside a div container, and you want the height of the container to adjust appropriately.

I know that there are multiple ways to achieve this, namely using a clearing div, a clearing :after pseudo-element, setting overflow:hidden, or (like in the example below) floating the container div.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
}
.container img {
  float: left;
}
.container p {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="somePic.jpg" />
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

I know that the container div (if not floated) does not adjust the height because its children (floated) are not part of the normal flow. Can someone explain why floating the container fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

Set your container `display` property to `block` or `inline-block` and `overflow:visible` makes it. See the sample code below:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.container img {
  float: left;
}
.container p {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.petsworld.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/cute-kittens.jpg" />
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander already gives you a possible solution to your problem, but if I correctly understood, you wanted to know "why" floating the container could solve the problem.

I searched around and I did not find an exaustive answer, anyway I found [reasons](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/) to avoid this method due to various drawbacks.

In general, we can say that floating an element extract it from normal document flow, and this is why its container naturally collapse to 0 height. Floating it too, extract this last one from document flow either, creating a different context that could contain floated children.

Comment: I am still more interested in understanding the behaviour of a float element in css rather than finding an alternative (I know to avoid this method, just curious why it works in the first place) The article you posted provides the reasons for not using it which is still great! Thanks a lot